# How could I have Pycharm to assign color on Class imported

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using Pycharm and VSCode and noticed in VScode, the imported class will be using the same color as the class definition but not on Pycharm,

How could I apply the same in Pycharm?

[imported package in Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ogji.png)
[imported package in VScode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvJMy.png)

[Pycharm Class build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EbYh.png)
[VSCODE class build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYSLo.png)

I tried to search the config but not fixed...

Answer (score 1):

Press Ctrl+Alt+S to open the IDE settings and select Editor | Color Scheme.
From the Scheme list, select a color scheme, click. , then click Import Scheme.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html#semantic-highlighting

Comment: thanks for the help, it just seems the eternal imported class in Pycharm is coloured like a normal function which is less colourful compared to VSCODE.